# iOS: Update UI while in Running in Location Services Background

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location, multitasking

I have a simple app that uses location services, and registers to run in the background.  I update a simple `tableView` with location data. This data is still being received when the user leaves the app and does something else.

Currently I am calling a method in my `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` to update the UI, but there is still a split second when the app opens, and the UI gets updated.

I have also tried to do periodic UI updates when in the background, but not surprisingly this doesn't seem to work.

**Are there any solutions out there so that I can have the UI fully updated when the user brings the app back into the foreground?**

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably be to profile and see why you have any delay at all before displaying new data.  It's quite possible you could do some things to get ready for the display to arrive, like doing Core Data queries ahead of time (they can take a significant amount of time).

An alternative would be to dump a blank UI bitmap from the screen as you were being suspended, and write to it directly based on activity - then when the application resumes, briefly show that bitmap as a screen overlay before showing the real complete UI.

Comment: I am not doing much when returning from the background. I am just getting an `NSSet` object from the current `NSManagedObject`, then sorting it as an array to display on the `UITableView`. Doesn't seem like it should be an expensive operation. What should I be watching for when profiling?  Duration?

Comment: Just whatever takes time for the display to update.  I would at least do the sorting before you come to the foreground.  Also it could be your table cells could be optimized to draw faster.